# iOS Calendar Format "days ago", "weeks ago", etc... not formatting correctly Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, uitableview

I'm loading data from Firebase Firestore into a table view and my cell.timeLabel.text needs to display the date as __ seconds ago (or if greater __ minutes ago, all the way to years ago). My current code isn't working and I even simulated a date that should return seconds ago but it said 12 hours for some reason. What's wrong and how do I solve this?

Extension Code:

```
extension Date {
    func years(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date, to: self).year ?? 0
    }
    func months(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: date, to: self).month ?? 0
    }
    func weeks(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekOfMonth], from: date, to: self).weekOfMonth ?? 0
    }
    func days(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: self).day ?? 0
    }
    func hours(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date, to: self).hour ?? 0
    }
    func minutes(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: date, to: self).minute ?? 0
    }
    func seconds(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date, to: self).second ?? 0
    }
    func offset(from date: Date) -> String {
        if years(from: date)   == 1 { return "\(years(from: date)) year ago"   } else { if years(from: date)   > 1 { return "\(years(from: date)) years ago"   } }
        if months(from: date)  == 1 { return "\(months(from: date)) month ago"  } else { if months(from: date)  > 1 { return "\(months(from: date)) months ago"  } }
        if weeks(from: date)   == 1 { return "\(weeks(from: date)) week ago"   } else { if weeks(from: date)   > 1 { return "\(weeks(from: date)) weeks ago"   } }
        if days(from: date)    == 1 { return "\(days(from: date)) day ago"    } else { if days(from: date)    > 1 { return "\(days(from: date)) days ago"    } }
        if hours(from: date)   == 1 { return "\(hours(from: date)) hour ago"   } else { if hours(from: date)   > 1 { return "\(hours(from: date)) hours ago"   } }
        if minutes(from: date) == 1 { return "\(minutes(from: date)) minute ago" } else { if minutes(from: date) > 1 { return "\(minutes(from: date)) minutes ago" } }
        if seconds(from: date) == 1 { return "\(seconds(from: date)) second ago" } else { if seconds(from: date) > 1 { return "\(seconds(from: date)) seconds ago" } }
        return ""
    }
}
```

TableView Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    let date1 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: payment.year, month: payment.month, day: payment.day, hour: payment.hour, minute: payment.minute, second: payment.second).date!
    let timeOffset = now.offset(from: date1)
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeOffset
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through your code?  Could you not just use a [RelativeDateTimeFormatter](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-show-a-relative-date-and-time-using-relativedatetimeformatter)?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Make sure to set your date components to the corresponding timezone. Where are you located? It seems you timezone offset from the payment timezone is 12 hours

Comment: Where are you setting your `now` variable? Why don't you use `Date()`? Where is `payment` coming from?